# Increase the Product Image Size in the Catalog Page

Tags: wordpress, image-resizing, woocommerce

I know, this is a simple fix (it has to be), but I have been searching for two days and haven't been able to accomplish this. The products in the catalog page of my site are too small.

Here is my site: <del>http://monocleprints.com/woo/shop/</del>

I have tried all the back-end things I can think of:

- changing the sizes in *WooCommerce -> Settings -> Catalog*
- resizing all the thumbnails with the Thumbnail Regenerator plugin
- resizing with the Simple Image Sizes tool (in the Media folder)

I realize that I might need to edit the css. Where would I go to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably better way to do this but you could try this:

Go to **plugins > Editor > Select woocommerce plugin** and open

`/assets/css/woocommerce.css`

Find this:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product
```

and change width to a larger percentage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a woocommerce theme you should check in the themes directory for woocommerce config files. These config files usually do the final styling on the images. For example, the file might be `your_theme/config-woocommerce/config.php` wherein you would find something like:

```
//product thumbnails
$avia_config['imgSize']['shop_thumbnail']   = array('width'=>80, 'height'=>80);
$avia_config['imgSize']['shop_catalog']     = array('width'=>450, 'height'=>355);
$avia_config['imgSize']['shop_single']      = array('width'=>450, 'height'=>355);
```

When in doubt, consult your theme's website/support forum as the question was probably already asked there.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent too much time today trying to figure out how to change the size of the thumbnails in the shopping cart and finally succeeded using CSS as follows:

```
.woocommerce table.cart img, .woocommerce #content table.cart img,
    .woocommerce-page table.cart img, .woocommerce-page #content table.cart img {
    width: 90px;
        height: auto;
        padding: none !important;
}
```

I hope that helps for you!

Answer (score 0):

Settings for this have been moved to the Theme Customizer.

**Design -> Customizer -> WooCommerce -> Productimages**

There is one setting for product pages and another for catalogue pages.

Tested in WooCommerce 3.3.3

Answer (score -1):

I was going trough the same problem, and I've found a possible solution for it.

Open the page where the image size is being changed, find the loop, e.g:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  // Loop code, thumbnail woocommerce function, etc

endwhile; endif;
```

and replace it with the code below:

```
query_posts($args); // Note: if there's no arguments for the query, it can be empty

//loop code, call the default thumnail function! the_post_thumnail()

rewind_posts();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the [guide on how to format your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - the bits about code formatting in particular.